# LibGdx Object Pool for many objects of the same parent class

Tags: java, android, object, libgdx, pool

In my game bullets are constantly created, therefore I want to use `Pool` class for this. However, the problem is that I have many types of bullets. All of them extend the same parent class `Projectile`. Currently there are 19 types of bullets. It's a bad idea to create a `Pool` class for each of them. And more may come later.

I tried to cast `BallistaArrow arrow =  (BallistaArrow) world.getPool().obtain();` . However I'm getting cast exception:

`[..].mygame.Projectile cannot be cast to [...].mygame.engineer.BallistaArrow` .

BallistaArrow is the child class of Projectile.

Is there any way to solve this problem, so that I can have one `Pool` class for all `Projectile` extending objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pool contains instances of a specific type.  Say it has 10 objects in it, those are going to be 10 specific `Projectile` instances, you cannot decide which type the object is *after* you extract it from the pool.

There are two ways to solve this, at least:

1. Use multiple pools, one per bullet type.  You can put a wrapper around the pools that knows which one to use based on a typed parameter.  This is probably not that bad of a solution.  An empty pool isn't a big deal.  You may have retention problems if some class of projectile is used for a while, and then isn't used (its pool will still be full).
2. Make your `Projectile` sub-types a run-time specialization, not a subclass.  So you just have a `Projectile` class that stores stuff common to all your bullets, and figure out the behavior difference at run-time.  See [Using Object Pools in Libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294757/using-object-pools-in-libgdx).

Comment: +1, but the third option would be to make an own Pool implementation which could handle this, but I'd still go with option 1.

Comment: If there is no better solution than having a lot of Pools, then I will go for the option 1. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @user2974885 Please accept the answers so it won't be listed as unanswered anymore.